# How to get audio samples/amplitude/frequency from streaming audio in flutter [audio_service]

Tags: flutter, audio, audio-service

I am using audio_service plugin for play audio from live streaming link. It's working fine but now i want to display music visualizer so i want some data from streaming audio like live sample bytes/ amplitude (db) / frequency so i can animated my visualizer base on data.

plugin : https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service

Comment: audio_service doesn't play audio, but just_audio does. Search the README of just_audio for "visualizer".

Comment: I have checked in just_audio plugin and i seen it created separate branch for it